# How can I deal with multilevel logistic regression with a well fitted null model?

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, multilevel-analysis

My null model have 80% of correct predictions. (multilevel with binary outcome).

That happens because 80% of respondents had answered "no" for the dependent variable.

Then, after add some independent variables I get something around 83% of correct responses. There are many significant predictors, however I can't make this model get better. I believe that is almost impossible to achieve a social-science-model with 90% of correct predictions.

Then, I want to know what I can do to test my model. Because I have many good predictors, and it doesn't make sense that nothing can explain my dependent variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to research imbalanced data, and modeling for rare levels in a dependent variable. You haven't provided enough information to say more than that.  I recommend you go through some online classes in data mining. (You don't have to take them from a college).

You could also plug the data into Watson Analytics.  It requires less knowledge of data mining than the other platforms I am aware of.

-V.  (M.S. Data Analytics)